# Prevent presenting the UIAlertViewController after navigating to the other view

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, swift4.2

I have one scenario when the user did not use the application for more than 5 min app will show a popup with session expiration message.

The code for session expiration is added in the `appDelegate` and from there the popup will be presented on the current view controller.

code is

```
@objc func applicationDidTimeout(notification: NSNotification) {
    if (window?.rootViewController?.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self))! {
        for view in window?.rootViewController?.view.subviews ?? [(window?.rootViewController?.view)!] {
            if view.isKind(of: MBProgressHUD.self) {
                return
            }
        }
        if window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController != nil {
            window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.showMessage(message: Message.sessionTimeout)
            })
        } else {
            self.showMessage(message: Message.sessionTimeout)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func showMessage(message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: appName, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let actionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: 0.3, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                CommonFunctions.setLoginAsRootVC()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(actionOkay)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now if the user is doing some data entry and at that time, if the user leaves application ideal for 5 min or more the keyboard will dismiss and the session expiration message shown there.

But as the text field's delegate method `textFieldShouldEndEditing` has some validation and if that validation fails it shows a popup with the message and ok button.

So when the user taps on the ok button in the session expiration message popup, it will redirect the user to the login screen but due to the text field's delegate method validation, it shows one pop up in the login screen.

Code for the validation fail message popup is

```
fileprivate func showErrorMessage(message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: appName, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let actionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.txtField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    alert.addAction(actionOkay)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**How to prevent the popup from being present in the login screen?**

Comment: You can try self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController..present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

I try to get the proper way to prevent the popup from appearing on the login screen.

But Finally, I found one heck to solve this issue.

I have declared one boolean in AppDelegate and set it's value to false when I want to prevent the popup from appearing and then revert it back to true when I want to show the popup.

I know this is not the elegant or efficient solution for the issue, but it works for now.

**If anyone knows the better answer can post here, I'm still open to any better solution.**

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func applicationDidTimeout(notification: NSNotification) 
{ 
 let visibleView : UIViewController = self.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(self.window?.rootViewController)!

 self.showMessage(message: Message.sessionTimeout,Controller: visibleView)
}

fileprivate func showMessage(message: String , Controller : UIViewController) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: appName, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let actionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
        //Now apply your code here to set login view controller as rootview
        // This controller is for demo
           window!.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: 
            nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview")
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    alert.addAction(actionOkay)
    Controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

//MARK:- Supporting method to get visible viewcontroller from window

```
func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(_ vc: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nc = vc as? UINavigationController {
            return self.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(nc.visibleViewController)
        } else if let tc = vc as? UITabBarController {
            return self.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tc.selectedViewController)
        } else {
            if let pvc = vc?.presentedViewController {
                return self.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(pvc)
            } else {
                return vc
            }
        }
    }
```

**Try this code, I've use this code many times may be it's work for you.**

Comment: Okay thank you @Jignesh Radadiya for your answer, Once I try, I will let you know about this.